# How to show an element equals the identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am given the relations $x^4=1$ and $y^3=1 $and $xyxyy=1$

How do I show that $x$ vanishes? My first approach was to come up with the order of the group and classify using Sylow theorems but that takes too much time. Is there a trick that can do it quickly?

I don’t need a complete proof but just a confirmation if $x$ vanished or not so if you can already tell which group these relations make up please let me know.

Comment: Adding the relation $y=1$ gives a group with generator $x$ and relations $x^4=1$ and $x^2=1$ which can be simplified to $x^2=1$.  Thus this group is the cyclic group of order $2$.  But your group surjects onto it, so $x$ can't be the identity in your group.

Comment: by ''$x$ vanishes'' you mean perhaps to say that the given conditions force $x=1_G$ ($G$ being the unspecified group you are working in)?

Comment: Yes that’s what I mean

Comment: Side note:  shouldn't be too hard to determine the group...multiplying your final relation on the right by $y$ gives $xyx=y$ which implies $xy=yx^3$.  Using this, any word in $x,y$ can be made into a word of the form $y^ax^b$ where $0≤a≤2$ and $0≤b≤3$.  So there are at most $12$ words in this group, so there aren't many groups to check.

Comment: Conjugating $x$ by $y$ three times gives $x^{-1}$, but $y^3=1$, so $x=x^{-1}$ and $x^2=1$. Now it is clear that the group is cyclic of order 6.